# clarification on static vs dynamic fragment

Tags: android

Good day, trying to clarify this: if i have this layout for a portrait layout

main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/configFragment_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.settingsFragment">
</fragment>
```

and this for landscape(mainly for tablets), main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/configFragment_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.example.SettingsFragment" ></fragment>

        <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.Example.DetailFragment" >
        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/details -->
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

now within my SettingFragment, i implement a button to go to the DetailFragment:

```
DetailFragment fragment = (DetailFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment_id);
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
                DetailFragment detailfragment = new WallpaperFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.detailFragment_id, detailfragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),DetailActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Am i now implementing a dynamic fragment or am i still using static fragment?.. or do i only use dynamic fragment when i use a viewgroup like FrameLayout in place of the fragment tag element?

Idea is to have a single pane for phones and multi-pane for tablets.I know its a bad idea to mix static and dynamic fragments, but its kind of confusing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You know, I might be wrong here (so feel free to correct me) but it looks like you're using both static AND dynamic fragments.  In your XML layouts you've added the fragments then you are re-instancing them via a fragment transaction in your activity.  Alternatively, if you had declared a container (FrameLayout for instance) instead of a fragment in your XML you would have to use a FragmentTransaction to add the fragment at run time.

In your example you are just stepping on the fragment that you all ready have.  Basically, the OS sees your fragment in the XML when inflating (I think that's when it calls the fragment code?) and executes the code associated with it via the tag in the fragment.  Your app then adds that same fragment over the top of itself.  A simple way to show this is to add a LogCat call in your Fragment class's onCreateView method.  If you see it more than once, then your stepping on the previous fragment with the same fragment (which I'm 99% sure you are).  Hope this helps to answer your question!

Answer (score 0):

Static fragments are defined in the layout and are not generally added or removed at runtime. They are referenced by their id in your code. They are generally put as a child element of a layout like below. Once they are defined here, android will know to make a fragment, that's all you have to do.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fooFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.TestFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Dynamic fragments are defined in your code and can be manipulated, added, removed, etc during runtime. They look like this:

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.your_placeholder, new TestFragment());
    ft.commit();
```